# Setting array object in struts2 hidden field

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 framework. I have a action that after some processing forwards to a result JSP.
Form of that action contains an array object and its setters and getters.
I am also using Model Driven Interface so that all the form fields are automatically get mapped.
Now, in the result JSP I want to set that array object in a hidden field so that on form submit that array object again get mapped but what happening is(let say my array elements are {1,2,3}) that hidden field tag is converting  this array in a String object as "1,2,3" and setting it as first element of  the array object. What should I do for this?

```
        <s:iterator value="licenseType" status="stat1">
<s:hidden name="licenseType[%{#stat1.index}]" />
</s:iterator>
<s:iterator value="status" status="stat2">
    <s:hidden name="status[%{#stat2.index}]" />
</s:iterator>
```

Action Class getting Form Value --->>

```
            int i=0;
    String h[]=activeLicenseReportForm.getLicenseType();
    String license ="";
    for(i=0; i<h.length; i++)
```

Setter and Getter in Form ----->>>

```
        public String[] getLicenseType() {
    return _licenseType;
      }

public void setLicenseType(String[]licenseType ) {
    this._licenseType=licenseType;

    }
```

Comment: One field -> one value. If you want to do this using only struts tags you would need to loop over your array and have a hidden field _for each_ item in the array. If all those fields have the same name then the form will send multiple values for the same variable - an array.

Answer (score 0):

For it to make sense to your application, the array of Object, for example, array of `Integer` will need to be converted to `String`. You need to create a `String` property in your action class, and call `Arrays.toString(arr)` before exiting your action class and set the value to the `String` property.

e.g.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private String myHiddenFieldArr;
    //getters and setters

    public String myAction() throws Exception
    {
        //Do you logic
        myHiddenFieldArr = Arrays.toString(your_Array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah my array is of String only I just used 1,2,3 for example.
Thank you for your helpful reply.

Comment: @Arpit So is it working now. If it is upvote and tick the answer.

Comment: No its not working its setting null to the array object

Comment: @Arpit I can't see the hidden field that you talked about in your post. Also post your action class code. You need to post code that will be meaningful to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

if arr1 is the name of the array you are passing into the jsp and arr1 is also the name of the array into the action to which you will be passing the array values to (ie in the next action) then you can use below:

```
<s:iterator value="arr1" status="stat">
    <s:hidden name="arr1[%{#stat.index}]" />
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my array with name packageList:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <s:select theme="simple" list="%{#request.packagesList}" listKey="packageId" listValue="packageName" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--" name="packageDetail" id="packageDetail" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now this packageList is mapped to my Action getter and Setter(OGNL stack)

```
public String getPackageDetail() {
    return packageDetail;
}

public void setPackageDetail(String packageDetail) {
    this.packageDetail = packageDetail;
}
```